# ASP.NET C# How to get user language from header?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any method to get the user language like the following java codes in C#?

```
request.getHeader("Accept-Language")
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use Request.UserLanguages. This propery contains a sorted string array of client language preferences [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userlanguages%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You can get the default client language, like this:

```
var userLanguages = Request.UserLanguages;
var ci = userLanguages.Count() > 0 
    ? new CultureInfo(userLanguages[0])
    : CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

Comment: this is really easy to use than this 
Request.Headers.GetValues("Accept-Language")
thank you

Comment: Be awaire with this apporach; `new CultureInfo()` will raise an exception if the sent language is formatted as '<lang>;<qualityValue>', or even '*' (match all languages). More informations on the Accept-Language syntax here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language .

Answer (score 2):

Extending on @alexmac's answer:

`Request.UserLanguages` returns an array of language-culture;priority pairs, see [Mozilla WebDocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language). Split the array items and discard the priority part, then filter for the "*" wildcard. The call to `new CultureInfo(cultureName)` will raise a `CultureNotFoundException` if cultureName is not found (was `ArgumentEcception` prior to .NEt 4), so I enclose it in a try/catch and default to `InvariantCulture`.

```
// get the user's language / culture settings from the 'accept-language' request header
var userLanguages = httpContext.Request.UserLanguages
    // split the 'language-culture;priority pair and use only the first part:
    .Select(userLanguageAndCultureWithPriority
        => userLanguageAndCultureWithPriority.Split(';')[0])
    // filter wildcard:
    .Where(userLanguageAndCulture => userLanguageAndCulture != "*")
    .ToArray();

CultureInfo ci;

try
{
    ci = userLanguages?.Count() > 0
        ? new CultureInfo(userLanguages[0])
        : CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
}
catch (CultureNotFoundException)
{
    ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
}
```